# SP2010: How to prevent a page from scrolling to a comment box

Tags: 2010, javascript, popup, comments

In my page, I have added a comment box. Now, when the page loads, it auto-scrolls to the position in the page where the comment box is present and where the cursor is. Is there any way to prevent scrolling using JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the scroll position once the page is loaded using below code in JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function(e){ 
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}
```

Comment: It's not working when I display this page as a popup (IsDlg=1)